# Javascript : how do i call a list of functions with parameters on window resize

Tags: javascript, parameters

Suppose i have written a few functions that accept parameters, like so:

`doSomething(name, class)`
`doSomething2(name, class)`
`doSomething3(name, class)`

```
var doit;
$(window).resize(function(){
clearTimeout(doit);
doit = setTimeout(doSomething(name, class),doSomething1(name,class),doSomething2(name,class), 300);
});
```

The above code should work well..

The Problem:

My code will be used by an end user and not me myself. I need a way to pass the parameters he/she passes to the setTimeOut function.. Eg. :

The end user is supposed to run the function like so `doSomething(name, class);`

What should i do to make sure that this function is auto called again (with the parameters that the end user passed) if browser is resized? Something like `bind` this function along with its passed parameters to the window resize event ?

Comment: Use media queries instead.

Comment: @SLaks The function needs to calculate something on window resize..